# Making a method idempotent

Tags: web-services, idempotent

Suppose we have a method deposit(Integer amount) in a class AccountManager. This method would modify the accountTotal and therefore is not idempotent.
How would you make this method idempotent?

Comment: Why would you _want_ to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A method that changes something based on the users input, like yours seems to do, cannot be made idempotent. This would mean that if you call `deposit(10)` a hundred times, only that it has the same effect as calling it once, which would not make any sense.

Comment: You didnt understand my question. By making it idempotent you prevent wrong requests from being executed on the server side. One solution I thought about is to pass a transactionId as an extra parameter and check on the server that the same transaction is not submitted twice.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence idempotence means exactly what i described. Also i did not think that adding and/or changing parameteres would be an option

Comment: I am looking for ideas. There are no specific constraints to the problem.

Comment: Well then i think that going with a unique transaction id, like you mentioned, is probably the best and easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

By passing the initial state of the state which you plan to change.  You can give a unique id to each modification and pass the id of the state with respect to which you are making the change.  Since the id would increase (or change in some way) after each change, subsequent requests for change with respect to the old id would do nothing (because the object would not be in the state with that id).  Think of this as a blanket "check in" operation in a CMS.  The files which haven't changed will not need to be checked in.  And after the initial check in of changes on files which did change, the subsequent blanket check ins will do nothing.